# SQLalchemy update multiple rows in single transaction

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

In plain SQL, I used to build SQL programmatically and execute, somthing like below:

```
users = [{"username": "bob", "is_admin": true}, {"username": "charley", "is_admin": false}, ..]

sql = ""
for in in range(len(users)):
   username = users[i]['username']
   is_admin = users[i]['is_admin']
   sql += """Update projects_users SET is_admin = {is_admin} WHERE project_id = (Select id from projects where name = {project_name}) AND user_id = (Select id from users where username = {username});""".format(project_name=project_name, username=username, is_admin=is_admin)

response = connect_and_execute_sql(sql)
```

Please note, in above code, I am building SQL query (separated by semicolon) and running all at once in single transaction.

But now when I am migrating this to SQLalchemy, I am facing problem building such query and executing it. Number of record to update could be upto 1000. So I cant afford to update one by one. I am using Fast API framework, so wondering there must be efficent way to do this.

Comment: Note that manually formatting strings to pass values to SQL queries is error prone and can lead to SQL injection. Use placeholders instead.

Answer (score -2):

This is my idea.

```py
true_admins = str({u['username'] for u in users if u['is_admin']}).strip("{}")
false_admins = str({u['username'] for u in users if not u['is_admin']}).strip("{}")
sql =f"""
Update projects_users SET is_admin = TRUE 
WHERE project_id IN (Select id from projects where name = {project_name}) AND 
user_id IN (Select id from users where username IN ({true_admins}) );

Update projects_users SET is_admin = FALSE 
WHERE project_id IN (Select id from projects where name = {project_name}) AND 
user_id IN (Select id from users where username IN ({false_admins}) );
"""
```

Comment: This idea is good but I am looking for similar solution in SQLalchemy.